# How to use \par normally in \author{}?

Tags: footnotes, titles

If I use `\par` in `\author{}`, it will produce errors when to compile the file. Then how to solve the problem？

The minimal working sample is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{\bf Arithmetization of Metamathematics in a General Setting}
\author{S. Feferman\thank{The results reported in this paper were obtained while the author was a student of Professor Alfred Tarski at the University of California, Berkeley. A more complete presentation of them has been given in the author's thesis [4]; announcement of the results has also been made in [5] and [6]. 
\par  We also indebted to Professor Alfred Tarski for a numlber of helpful suggestions regarding this research; as well as to Professor Leon Henkin for his kind guidance durihg the period 19155-56 while Professor Alfred Tarski was on leave. We wish also to thank Professors Jolm Myhill and Georg Kreisel, both for a number of stimulating conversations, and also the latter for his helpful comments on a draft of this paper. 
\par Finally，thanks are due to Professor Steven Orey for his interest in widening the range of application of our work, as will be evidenced at various points in the text.
\par This paper was prepared under Contract DA-04-200-0RD-997 for the Office of Ordnance research, U.S.A.}\\ Stanford, California}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The method of arithmetization

\end{document}
```

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: you shouldn't use `\bf` in latex (it is not defined by default) and certainly not in a `\title`

Comment: @David Carlisle I always use it in this way but it arises no problem.

Comment: perhaps, but it is always wrong:-)  the main design aim of latex is that such styling is specified by the `\documentclass` if you put formatting in titles and section headings etc you defeat that, secondly `\bf` isn't defined in latex, it is just added in article class for compatibility with documents written before 1993, so if you change class it may give undefined command errors, If you want bold titles it is much better to customise `\maketitle` to do that than to put formatting into the document text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle All good comments.  I have now shown how to patch in my answer.

Comment: @AndrewSwann :-)

Comment: @David Carlisle Good answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such situations you can use `\endgraf` instead of `\par`.  Incidentally the command is `\thanks`, not `\thank`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE \@title \par}{\LARGE\bfseries \@title \par}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Arithmetization of Metamathematics in a General Setting}

\author{S. Feferman\thanks{The results reported in this paper were
obtained while the author was a student of Professor Alfred Tarski at
the University of California, Berkeley. A more complete presentation
of them has been given in the author's thesis [4]; announcement of the
results has also been made in [5] and [6].
\endgraf We also indebted to Professor Alfred Tarski for a numlber of
helpful suggestions regarding this research; as well as to Professor
Leon Henkin for his kind guidance durihg the period 19155-56 while
Professor Alfred Tarski was on leave. We wish also to thank Professors
Jolm Myhill and Georg Kreisel, both for a number of stimulating
conversations, and also the latter for his helpful comments on a draft
of this paper.
\endgraf Finally, thanks are due to Professor Steven Orey for his
interest in widening the range of application of our work, as will be
evidenced at various points in the text.
\endgraf This paper was prepared under Contract DA-04-200-0RD-997 for
the Office of Ordnance research, U.S.A.}\\ Stanford, California}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The method of arithmetization\dots

\end{document}
```

Thanks to egreg a unicode comma after "Finally" has been replaced by an ordinary comma.  You should use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{...}` instead of `\bf`, cf. [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/15925).

Furthermore it is best not to include such formatting in the `\title` argument, as the document may wish to use that text elsewhere, but to patch the title printing macro used by `\maketitle`, as I have done above.  Alternatively you may use the [`titling` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) to change the styling of the title in `article` class: in this case you would write

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
```

to add the `\bfseries` to the title.

Comment: For mysterious reasons, after `Finally` the comma is U+FF0C FULLWIDTH COMMA, which causes it to disappear from the output. More important: `\bf` should not be used for whatsoever reason.

Comment: @egreg Many thanks.  The comma is from the OP, but I have now fixed that, and the horrible `\bf`.  I would prefer not to have any formatting command there at all.

Comment: I fixed the comma after "finally". But what problems will it arise if we use `\bf` in the title?

Comment: @Kuttens `\bf` is plain TeX syntax and obsolete for LaTeX since 1994.